# Simplex LP Value of in Pyhton

Tags: python, automation, linear-programming, pulp, excel-solver

**Use Python for solving a Linear Programming porblem with the objective being a Value of: x**

Hello people of internet

I'm having trouble with a process I'm trying to automatize in Python it´s a LP problem

I found **Simplex LP method in Solver from Excel** very useful to solve one problem at the time but I need to do it for 1000 or more problems so I really want to save me some time

PuLP is very good doing Solver stuff but only if you want to maximize or minimize the objective function and **I need to equalize it to a VALUE OF:**

So the problem is this one:

I need to divide the payment into 3 debts, but I cannot make partial payments

I figured I can multiply the debts times a boolean (1 or 0) in a way that the objective (a sum product) equalizes the payment

So the money from the payment would go only to the debts I can completely cover

Solver works like this

[Solver Excel Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aExrJ.png)

And it gives the correct way to divide the payments

[Solver Excel Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTfEA.png)

So I need to do the same thing for Python Maybe there's a secret function PuLP has that can help me solve this or maybe Sympy or another library, idk I'd really appreciate your help

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [['Debt1', 100, 400, True], ['Debt2', 200, 400, True], ['Debt3', 300, 400, True]]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Debt', 'Amount', 'Payment', 'Boolean'])
df

    Debt    Amount  Payment Boolean
0   Debt1   100     400     True
1   Debt2   200     400     True
2   Debt3   300     400     True
```

Comment: Please post the actual code, not the images and provide the inputs and corresponding expected outputs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured how to do it, here's the code

```
bills = [100, 200, 300]
payment=400
c=0
ceros=[0]* len(rets) 
lista = [item for sublist in zip(ceros, bills) for item in sublist]+[0]      
##Divide payment
payment_div = [] 
for n in range(1, len(bills) + 1):  
    for combination in it.combinations(lista, len(bills)): 
        if c > 1000000: 
            break 
#Some times with different and many values in bills it'd end in infinite loop, break is for exit
            payment_div=[] 
        else: 
            c=c+1 
            if sum(combination) == payment: 
                payment_div.append(combination) 
#Payment div will have all the possible combinations, if empty then there's no possible combinations that equal the x value 
if not payment_div: 
    print("No possible combinations")
else: #This will find the best matching combination to the original bills list
    divi=set(payment_div) 
    divis=list(divi) 
    counts=[] 
    for i in range (len(divis)): 
        div=divis[i] 
        counti=sum(div == bills for div, bills in zip(div, bills)) 
        counts.append(counti) 
    maxx=max(counts) 
    maxind=[index for index, value in enumerate(counts) if value == maxx] 
    for n in range (len(maxind)): 
        op=divis[maxind[n]] 
print(op)

output: (100, 0, 300)
```